# operator= overload in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I need some help with operator assignment. This is code:

**Sinusoid.h:**

```
class Sinusoid : public Component
{   
    float fs, f, A, fi;
    int N;
    double *array;

public:
    Sinusoid(float fs, float f, float Ts, float fi, float A);
    void count(int type=1);
    void clear();
    ~Sinusoid();
    double *getArray() { return this->array; }
    double*& operator=(Sinusoid* const &rhs) {
        return rhs->array;
    };
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "headers.h"
int main()
{
    int N = 1000 * 2.5;
    Sinusoid *sinus = new Sinusoid(1000, 15, 2.5, (M_PI / 4), 0.7);
    double **answers = new double*[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        answers[i] = new double[N];
    }
    //lab1
    //Zad1
    sinus->count(1);
    answers[0] = sinus;
    return 0;
    }
```

When i build this code i've got the following problem:

**C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'Sinusoid *' to 'double *' main.cpp:15**

I know that i can assign two classes with overloaded operator "=" but i want to take a private member of class (double *array;). I know that i can do it by "getArray()" method but i want to learn more "beautiful" practice. Hope you will help me.

Thank you.

Comment: *answers[0] = sinus ?

Comment: yep, i know that i can't use sinus->array because it's private member of the class - i want to use overloaded operator "=" to assign this to the answers variable

Comment: even if i do *answers[0] it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `double*& operator=(Sinusoid* const &rhs)` operator doesn't do what you apparently think it does.

An `operator=` member function allows you to have an instance of the class (`Sinusoid`) on the left side of an assignment and an instance of the parameter type (`Sinusoid*`) on the right side. So what you wrote would let you do:

```
Sinusoid* pointer = whatever;
Sinusoid object;
object = pointer;
```

Obviously that's not what you intended. (And probably not something you'll ever want.)

The return type of the `operator=` doesn't have any influence on this fundamental usage. All it means is that the result of `object = pointer` is then a `double*&`. So it would let you write:

```
double* foo;
foo = (object = pointer);
```

And that's still not helpful for what you want.

Since `answers[0]` is a pointer, there's no way to create a custom assignment operator for it. However the language has a different mechanism which can be used here. You can create an implicit conversion operator for your class so that compiler is allowed to convert/decay it into a different type when reasonable. Try adding the following to your class:

```
operator double* () {
    return rhs->array;
}
```

That should work for the case you want.

Although personally I don't think there's anything wrong with leaving the usage to require calling `getArray()` in the first place. Sometimes the clarity of an explicit function call can make it easier to read what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
class Sinusoid : public Component {
...
   operator double*()  {
       return array;
   }
```

and the usage

```
answers[0] = *sinus;
```